# Sending parameters with HTTP post request

Tags: c#, controller, httprequest, asp.net-web-api2

I am doing a HTTP request from my C# project to a controller I have. I am using webapi 2 in both cases. I manage to enter the controller's method but when I check the data I send it stays null or since I am using 'dynamic' variable it just says: 'object'.

Here is the code which I send:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/MyPage/api/user/login/" );

var postData = string.Format( "={0};{1}", user.username, user.password );

var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( postData );

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write( data, 0, data.Length );
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

var responseString = new StreamReader( response.GetResponseStream() ).ReadToEnd();
```

And in the controller I expect to have dynamic filled with username and password:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("login")]
public IHttpActionResult LoginUser( [FromBody]dynamic user )
{
    if (user == null)
    {
        const string message = "Object is null";
    }

    string username;
    string password;

    try
    {
        username = user.username;
        password = user.password;
    }
}
```

Here user just shows object and user.username and user.password are null. I tried using NameValueCollection or Byte array. None of those worked.

I found workaround but I doesn't sound good to me. If I send string with '=' sign in front I get the string. For example I can send "=username;password" but It doesn't seem generic and elegant. Is there a normal way to send the two?

Comment: UrlEncoded data is in form `key1=value1&key2=value2` and has nothing to do with json.

Comment: I tried doing the reuqest by sending NameValueCollection but it didn't work as well. 
And if you mean this is wrong: "Invalid JSON object", I know just forgot to remove it